# How to select distinct days, excluding time of that day

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

This is my table

```
+---------------------+
| access_time         |
+---------------------+
| 2014-02-17 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-15 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-15 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-15 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-15 11:00:00 |
| 2014-02-14 02:00:00 |
| 2014-02-13 18:00:00 |
| 2014-02-13 12:50:05 |
| 2014-02-13 12:48:57 |
| 2014-02-13 11:57:24 |
+---------------------+
```

and I want to have an output like this:

```
+---------------------+
| access_time         |
+---------------------+
| 2014-02-17 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-15 12:00:00 |
| 2014-02-14 02:00:00 |
| 2014-02-13 18:00:00 |
+---------------------+
```

What SQL command to have that kind of output?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? Or SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want one arbitrary time per day, you can do:

```
select access_time
from table t
group by date(access_time);
```

More typically,you would choose which of the times you would want, and do something like:

```
select min(access_time)
from table t
group by date(access_time);
```

Answer (score 3):

For SQL Server 2008 or more recent versions, I'd recommend:

```
select cast(access_time as date)
from t
group by cast(access_time as date)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
With cte as (Select *,row_number ()over(partion by convert(date,access_time) 
             order by access_time desc) rn from <yourtable>)
Select * from <yourtable> where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try on this

> select distinct cast(access_time as Date) from tablename group by date